# Chrome Webdriver - badge NOT showing on Webdriver but they show in Chrome browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, badge, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Chrome Webdriver for my automation, and I noticed a difference between the normal Chrome browser and the Webdriver Browser.

The html page contains code:

`<span class="badge badge-warning ng-binding" id="notificationAlert" .....`

Chrome will show the badge, but Chrome Webdriver will not show the badge.

Has anyone noticed this oddity?
I set my test case to detect new notifications for 2 minutes but it then passes out because the badge does not appear.

But in my browser it will appear within 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you have live URL to see? Does this element present but not visible in webdriver?

Comment: Thanks for replying? Can you help? I have the same URL for using both normal chrome browser and the Webdriver Browser in AUtomation. This element is not present in webdriver, it doesnt even show the badge at all.